# I can't get Graal Online to work

Tags: command-line, games

I checked, and my computer is 64bit. The file i downloaded is 64bit. I've tried the following things ->

```
    uname -m
    ./Graal
    ls
    cd Downloads/
    ls
    ./Graal 
    sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2
```

The file opens, but it only shows a black screen. Running 14.04 on a mid 2012 Macbook Pro. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a bit vague. Firstly, what file did you download, and where from? Are you running on a virtual machine or is Ubuntu installed on the MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

The Graal Online client currently doesn't work on Linux as of around the 2nd of February because the GraalOnline servers require you to have the most updated version of the client which is 6.111 for Mac OSX and 6.113 for Windows while the Linux client is still at 6.037 and was last updated in November 2012. See [Source](http://forums.graalonline.com/forums/showthread.php?p=1735239)

Below is a screenshot I took of the problem which is also in the source I provided.

[image: GraalOnline client error]

Here is the output from the Graal Client when running it through the terminal. It states that the client is outdated and directs the user to upgrade which isn't possible as no new client for Linux exists.

```
michael@enyo:~$ cd /mnt/storage/graal/graal4/
michael@enyo:/mnt/storage/graal/graal4$ ./Graal_6.037-64 
Direct Rendering is enabled, Graal should run smoothly.
Data directory: /mnt/storage/graal/graal4/
User data directory: /home/michael/.graal/graal4/
Scanning files ...
Scanning done.
Graal has been activated!
Loading tile definitions for server Login
Connecting to the game server...
Done.
Please update your Graal version!
Initialized OpenGL.
michael@enyo:/mnt/storage/graal/graal4$
```

Comment: You might be able to get some traction getting in touch with Graal Online support. email address can be found here: http://www.graalonline.com/zone/support/graaldesk

Comment: @ElderGeek Support emails rarely work as I've heard people waiting up to 6 months+ to get a reply. The game also has a support center that can be found @ [support.toonslab.com](http://support.toonslab.com/) which may work better. The website should show the support center link instead but it is bit ambiguous as it hasn't really been updated in years and most of the information on it is outdated. Additionally, the GraalOnline management know of these issues but have not been forthcoming with information regarding any progress towards a fix.

Comment: It's sad how the level of customer support has dropped over the years.

Comment: It is sad but it is to be expected as most of the support teams on GraalOnline are essentially volunteers and the one person who got things done on the development side especially when it came to Linux has since left. I will leave it there as I don't want to get into GraalOnline politics.

Comment: I expect the latter is the root cause and the former is hopefully unrelated. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
chmod +x ./Graal
./Graal
```